# Return variables from inside function back outside

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return, addition

```
var n1;
var n2;
function Restart() {
  n1= Number(prompt("Enter a number", ""));
  n2= Number(prompt("Enter another number", ""));
  return (n1, n2);
}
function Add() {
  n1+n2;
  alert(n1+n2);
}
```

how would i be able to bring back the variable n1 and n2 outside from function Restart()?

Comment: how would i be able to bring back the variable n1 and n2 outside from function Restart()?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please read about [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and make sure your question is in the Question, not in the comments. :)

Comment: There's no need for the return statement. Since you declare n1 and n2 outside of the Restart function, these variables will keep their value after the function ReStart function executes. So if you run Add after Restart, Add will have whatever values were set in Restart.

Comment: I executed the Restart() function, but when i execute the add function it says Nan. The values remain inside the Restart function.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle to show you how this works: http://jsfiddle.net/y7j8ko4k/1/ Just press test.

Comment: i cant get mine to work

Comment: @ransom: the code will not work in a vacuum: you need an event handler that triggers the execution, which is why in the jsfiddle I have a button and when you press the button then the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `Restart()` anywhere, so it is hard to answer precisely. In the code you wrote, `n1` and `n2` are in a wider scope than both `Restart` and `Add`, so both functions will have access to them. The `return` is incorrect, but thankfully not actually needed.

If you don't like the idea of globalish variables (and that is a perfectly good stance to take), you can return a structure (an array or an object).

- In case of an array, `return [n1, n2]` should do it; if you invoke `var values = Restart()`, you can access `n1` as `values[0]`, and `n2` as `values[1]`.
- In case of an object, you'd do `return { n1: n1, n2: n2 }`; and access them as `values.n1` and `values.n2`.

**EDIT:**

> the array return [n1, n2] doesnt work

It most certainly does.

```js
function Restart() {
  var n1= Number(prompt("Enter a number", ""));
  var n2= Number(prompt("Enter another number", ""));
  return [n1, n2];
}
function Add() {
  values = Restart();
  var n1 = values[0];
  var n2 = values[1];
  alert(n1+n2);
}
Add();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this help you?

```
function Restart() {
  n1= Number(prompt("Enter a number", ""));
  n2= Number(prompt("Enter another number", ""));
  return {"n1":n1, "n2":n2};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer. The code is fine, you just need to call your functions:

```
var n1;
var n2;
function Restart() {
  n1= Number(prompt("Enter a number", ""));
  n2= Number(prompt("Enter another number", ""));
}
function Add() {
  alert(n1+n2);
}
Restart();
Add();
```

Comment: I rather doubt that `return (n1, n2);` is doing what the OP wants.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not doing anything, but it doesn't have to either.

Comment: So, why do you leave it there, then?  It just makes the code look confusing and misleading.  The whole concept here of using globals like this is pretty horrible.

Comment: @jfriend00 well, it's not my answer .. but as you wish ;-)

Comment: to me it seems he or she is simply learning the ropes. i agree something like this on a real page would be bad-news-bears.